# Is getExpire in minutes a documentation error?

Tags: joomla-3.x, session, jsession, documentation

I believe I've found a mistake in the Joomla documentation, according to the [docs](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JSession.html#method_getExpire)

> getExpire should get session expiration time in minutes.

I've checked my settings and the session lifetime is set to 15minutes
[image: Session Settings]

but when I use the following code

```
$expiry=$session->getExpire();  
echo "session expiration is ",$expiry,"<br/>";
```

The result is "session expiration is 900". I'm assuming the result is in seconds 15*60=900.

**QUESTIONs:**

- Can someone confirm that getExpire() normally returns the result in seconds?
- Who should you contact if you think you have found a problem with the Joomla
  documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Yes, `getExpire()` returns result in seconds. As you can see [here](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/9e948130acb79d189255625df47c0b57afc00534/libraries/cms/application/cms.php#L718) and [here](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/3cfe5ab695825b5ed8edf22a8c227c7974968de9/libraries/joomla/factory.php#L595), they are converting `lifetime` value to seconds (default is 15 minutes, so 900 seconds).
- Documentation is automatically generated from source code. So you should create a [new issue](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues) and describe the bug. Or I can do that. Let me know.

Comment: I'll leave it to you Rene. Sorry and thanks :)

Comment: Okay. No problem.

Comment: Made [issue](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues/8843) and PR to fix this. Issue is now closed, so this bug is removed.